# How do I query the results of a group by statement?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to run another group by on the results of my first group by call. Essentially I want to get the count of all the counts if that makes sense.

```
select token_id, count(token_id) from nft.asset_traits
where collection_address = '0xbc4ca0eda7647a8ab7c2061c2e118a18a936f13d'
group by token_id;
```

this returns two columns
token_id, count

I want to now group by on the counts, essentially find how many tokens have the same number of traits.

Comment: You can take your query as subquery and do a further group by, but I'm sceptical if this is really the best option in your case. Maybe you could show some sample input and expected outcome?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select no_token, count(token_id) no_token_id
from
(
    select token_id, count(token_id) no_token
    from nft.asset_traits
    where collection_address = '0xbc4ca0eda7647a8ab7c2061c2e118a18a936f13d'
    group by token_id
)
group by no_token
```